# Why not read all lines from text file?

Tags: kotlin

In my Kotlin project in folder `src/resources/` I has file `pairs_ids.txt`.

[image]

This is a property file:

```
key=value
```

The count of all lines are **1389**.

Here code that read content of this file line by line.

```
open class AppStarter : Application<AppConfig>() {
    override fun getName() = "stats"

    override fun run(configuration: AppConfig?, environment: Environment?) {
        val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)

        val inputStream = javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/pairs_ids.txt")
        val isr = InputStreamReader(inputStream)
        val br = BufferedReader(isr)
        for (line in br.lines()) {
            logger.info("current_line = " + line)
        }
        br.close()
        isr.close()
        inputStream.close()
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    AppStarter().run(*args)
}
```

The problem is that count of **current_line** is every time different.

Start project - the count of **current_line** is **803**.

Start again project -  the count of **current_line** is **1140**.

Why every time the count is different and not equal to **1389**?

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin has some brilliant extension methods to easily deal with streams, reading lines and text and such.

Try this:

```
open class AppStarter : Application<AppConfig>() {
    override fun getName() = "stats"

    override fun run(configuration: AppConfig?, environment: Environment?) {
        val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)
        javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/pairs_ids.txt").bufferedReader().use { reader -> reader.readLines() }.forEach { line -> logger.info(line) }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    AppStarter().run(*args)
}
```

When playing with input/output streams, use Kotlin's `use` extension methods, and do all of your processing inside of the `use` block.

This will handle all opening and closing of the streams so that there are no leaks, or forgetting to close/flush etc.

Comment: I'm not need to read whole text in ONE line. I need to read file line by line. Then I will pass every line as param for external method.

Comment: I found the problem. If replace logger.info by println then success work. The count is always 1389. Why  for loop not work correct with logger?

Comment: Not help. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54673250/why-kotlins-loop-for-not-work-correct-with-org-slf4j-logger

Answer (score 0):

Given an `InputStream`, you can use [`forEachLine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-reader/for-each-line.html) to read each line separately:

```
inputStream.bufferedReader().use {
    it.forEachLine {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

Note: You should use [`use`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html) which is a convenient way to make sure the stream is closed once the reading is done (as user8159708 already suggested).

Comment: Not help. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54673250/why-kotlins-loop-for-not-work-correct-with-org-slf4j-logger?noredirect=1#comment96137899_54673250