# Why Kotlin's loop (for) not work correct with org.slf4j.Logger?

Tags: kotlin, slf4j

In my Kotlin project in folder src/resources/ I has file pairs_ids.txt.

Here code:
This is a property file:

```
key=value
```

The count of all lines are **1389**.

Here code that read content of this file line by line.

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Exchange")

 private var allSymbolsIDsMap: Map<String, String> = mapOf()    
 val pairsIDs = getResourceAsText("/pairs_ids.txt")
 allSymbolsIDsMap = pairsIDs.split(",").associate {
 val (left, right) = it.split("=")
          left to right.toString()
 }
 logger.info("allSymbolsIDsMap_size = " + allSymbolsIDsMap.size)
 var countAllSymbolHandler = 0
 for ((key, value) in allSymbolsIDsMap) {
   countAllSymbolHandler++
   logger.info("countAllSymbolHandler = $countAllSymbolHandler")
}

private fun getResourceAsText(path: String): String {
    return object {}.javaClass.getResourceAsStream(path).bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
}
```

Result:

Start project:

```
allSymbolsIDsMap_size = 1389
Start project - "countAllSymbolHandler =" print 1113 times
```

Again start project:

```
allSymbolsIDsMap_size = 1389
"countAllSymbolHandler =" print 242 times
```

If replace `logger.info` by simple `println` then success work. The count is always **1389**.

Why loop (for) not work correct with **logger**?

Comment: `this::class.java` is too long, just `javaClass` is the best

Comment: @EugenePetrenko length is irrelevant. `javaClass` is also discouraged, and IntelliJ will complain about it.

Comment: Also, isn't this pretty much a repost of https://stackoverflow.com/q/54671346/6296561?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
override fun run(configuration: AppConfig?, environment: Environment?) {
        val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)
        javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/pairs_ids.txt").bufferedReader().use { reader -> reader.readLines() }.forEach { line -> logger.info(line) }
    }
```

When playing with input/output streams, use Kotlin's `use` extension methods, and do all of your processing inside of the `use` block.

This will handle all opening and closing of the streams so that there are no leaks, or forgetting to close/flush etc.